# How to flatten list of list values in groupBy in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, collections

I have an object structure

```
data class File(val travelBatch: List<TravelBatch>) {
    data class TravelBatch(
        val currency: String,
        val transactions: List<Transaction>
    )
}
```

I want to have a map of currency to transactions. The below code I tried gives
`Map<String, List<List<Transaction>>` I want `Map<String, List<Transaction>`

```
file.travelBatch.groupBy({it.currency}, {it.transactions})
```

Need help to flatten the values in the map in kotlin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`mapValues`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-values.html)

```
val result = file.travelBatch
    .groupBy({ it.currency }, { it.transactions })
    .mapValues { it.value.flatten() }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot @IR42. I was trying it for almost an hour!